Can I create a filter in biblatex publist to filter other people's publications?
I'd like to write a cover letter citing other people's publications followed by printing my own publications. Something like the opposite of filter=mine would be helpful. Please see the uncommented line in the code below for what I have in mind. Is this possible?
\documentclass{article}

\newcommand*\publistbasestyle{mla}
%\usepackage[backref=true, style=publist]{biblatex}
\usepackage[
    style=publist, 
    doi=true,
    date=year, 
    url=true,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=true,
    plnumbering=global,
    linktitles=doi,
    maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
\plauthorname[Michel]{Goossens}

\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-books.bib}
@Book{knuth1990,
            author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
            title     = {The {\TeX}book },
            year      = {1990},
            isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
            publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
            note = {Some extra text},
            annotation = {Text}
}
        
@Book{goossens1993,
            author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
            title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
            year      = "1993",
            publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
            address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
}
\end{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{\jobname-articles.bib}
        @Article{greenwade1993,
        author  = "George D. Greenwade",
        title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
        year    = "1993",
        journal = "TUGBoat",
        volume  = "14",
        number  = "3",
        pages   = "342--351",
                    annotation = {Text}
}
\end{filecontents}
    
\usepackage{hyperref}

\hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,
        linkcolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue,
}

\addbibresource{\jobname-articles.bib}
\addbibresource{\jobname-books.bib}
\begin{document}
        Here is my cover letter in which I would like to cite \parencite{goossens1993} and \parencite{greenwade1993},
        \tableofcontents
        
\clearpage

        \nocite{*}
        
% \printbibliography[title={Other people's publications}, filter=notmine]

\printbibliography[title={My publications},type={book}, filter=mine]


        
\end{document}


You don't need such a filter in the case you sketched. Just use \refsections and no filter on the "others" reference list:
    \documentclass{article}
    
    \newcommand*\publistbasestyle{mla}
    %\usepackage[backref=true, style=publist]{biblatex}
    \usepackage[
    style=publist, 
    doi=true,
    date=year, 
    url=true,
    hyperref=true,
    backref=true,
    plnumbering=global,
    linktitles=doi,
    maxbibnames=10]{biblatex}
    \plauthorname[Michel]{Goossens}
    
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname-books.bib}
        @Book{knuth1990,
            author    = {Knuth, Donald E.},
            title     = {The {\TeX}book },
            year      = {1990},
            isbn      = {0-201-13447-0},
            publisher = {Addison\,\textendash\,Wesley},
            note = {Some extra text},
            annotation = {Text}
        }
        
        @Book{goossens1993,
            author    = "Michel Goossens and Frank Mittelbach and Alexander Samarin",
            title     = "The LaTeX Companion",
            year      = "1993",
            publisher = "Addison-Wesley",
            address   = "Reading, Massachusetts"
        }
    \end{filecontents}
    \begin{filecontents}{\jobname-articles.bib}
        @Article{greenwade1993,
            author  = "George D. Greenwade",
            title   = "The {C}omprehensive {T}ex {A}rchive {N}etwork ({CTAN})",
            year    = "1993",
            journal = "TUGBoat",
            volume  = "14",
            number  = "3",
            pages   = "342--351",
            annotation = {Text}
        }
    \end{filecontents}
    
    \usepackage{hyperref}
    
    \hypersetup{
        colorlinks,
        citecolor=blue,
        filecolor=blue,
        linkcolor=blue,
        urlcolor=blue,
    }
    
    \addbibresource{\jobname-articles.bib}
    \addbibresource{\jobname-books.bib}
    \begin{document}
    \newrefsection
        Here is my cover letter in which I would like to cite \citesecitem{knuth1990} and \citesecitem{greenwade1993},
        \tableofcontents
        
        \clearpage
        
        
        \printbibliography[title={Other people's publications}]
        
    \newrefsection
        \nocite{*}
        \printbibliography[title={My publications},type={book}, filter=mine]
        
    \end{document}

Adding notmine would require multiple redefinitions.
